# Sending a post request via C++ desktop application

Tags: php, c++, http, post, request

I'm using [SFML::Network](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/group__network.php) to access my web server and send it high scores. The high scores are recieved by a PHP script that stores them on a JSON file:

```
...
$name = $_POST["n"];
$validator = $_POST["v"];
$score = $_POST["s"];
...
```

I'm currently sending a POST request from C++ like this:

```
...
Http http; http.setHost("http://mywebsite.com");
Request request("script.php", Http::Request::Post);
request.setBody("n=" + mName + "&v=" + mValidator + "&s=" + toStr(mScore));
http.sendRequest(request);
...
```

This works, but has the same limitations as a GET request - especially character limit. Since I need to validate the high scores for custom levels made in LUA, I wanted to pass the whole LUA file (stripped of symbols and whitespace) as mValidator. But it doesn't work with 1000 characters. Small strings work properly.

I've been told that character limit is only present in GET requests, and that I'm calling the POST request in the wrong way.

How can I call the POST request correctly and avoid the character limit without compressing my parameters?

Comment: Looks like there is an SFML forum.. have you asked on there?

Comment: @Pete: I will - I thought SO was more suitable because there are many HTTP client libraries for C++ that can send POST requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 characters should work fine.  Check to make sure your string is properly encoded.  A content-type of `x-www-form-urlencoded` should be URL encoded.